I want to validate my input type time from the today date and after current time
<input type="date" onChange={(e)=>setDate(e.target.value)}/>
<input type="time" onChange={(e)=>setTime(e.target.value)} />
if the date is after today and time is after current time i want to show validation that "please select precious time" .
I want the validation on time and date.

You can achieve this by creating a new Date object with the current date and time, and then comparing it with the selected date and time.
So your react component should look like the below:
const [date, setDate] = useState("");
const [time, setTime] = useState("");
const [error, setError] = useState("");

const handleDateChange = (e) => {
  const selectedDate = new Date(e.target.value);
  const currentDate = new Date();
  if (selectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) < currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)) {
    setError("please select precious time");
  } else {
    setDate(e.target.value);
    setError("");
  }
};

const handleTimeChange = (e) => {
  if (date) {
    const selectedDateTime = new Date(`${date}T${e.target.value}`);
    const currentDateTime = new Date();
    if (selectedDateTime.getTime() < currentDateTime.getTime()) {
      setError("please select precious time");
    } else {
      setTime(e.target.value);
      setError("");
    }
  } else {
    setTime(e.target.value);
  }
};

// In your render method
<input type="date" onChange={handleDateChange} />
<input type="time" onChange={handleTimeChange} />
{error && <p>{error}</p>}

